Dask running very slow
I am new to using Dask. I have a small piece of code like below.
In this code, I am triggering computation on.
  el.compute()

Is this the correct way to use Dask's compute function?
My code runs very very slow as each element is basically a shell command that writes something to the same output file.
#!/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import re
import subprocess
import numpy as np

from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da

def make_arr(max_num):
 my_arr = []
 for i in range(0,max_num):
   my_arr.append(str(i))
 return my_arr

def create_data(crnum):
 detailed_list = []
 for el in crnum:
   el = str(el)
   #### shell_cmd_x is actually a shell command that takes each element and writes to the same output file. We do this using subprocess.run(shell_cmd_x, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True) ####
   shell_cmd_x = '/path/to/my_shell_executable' + ' ' + el
   run_x = shell_cmd_x
   detailed_list.append(run_x)
 np_arr = np.array(detailed_list, dtype=str)
 return np_arr

def main():
 list_n = make_arr(100)
 client = Client()
 dask_arr = da.asarray(list_n, chunks=10)
 result = dask_arr.map_blocks(create_data, dtype=str)
 for el in result:
   #### Is this the right way to use Dask compute()? ####
   print(el.compute())

if __name__=='__main__':
 main()


Hi, I'm not sure of what you are trying to do. In the end, if using Dask Array, you should just call compute on the end Array to get a Numpy one, so result.compute() in your case. But I'm not sure in your example how you call the shell command, and what do you expect. Dask is working in memory, not on disk.
